# multiselect option using databricks widgets

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, databricks

I have like 10 to 12 columns in my data frame. I need to add a multiselect widget where i can select
either all columns or only some columns and store the result as a list.
if tomorrow the column values are increased, I need to add those to widget as well.
How to solve this used case?

ex column names from A-L

I need all columns listed and the user can select either all columns or only few, and al the selected columns should be stored as list

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [multiselect](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/widgets.html) widget to do so. The choices are the columns of the dataframe. I've added one additional choice `'*'` to select all columns. This will be default selection (you can only have a single entry as default).

Edit: added a check for the case where no column is selected.

Setup sample df and widget

```
df = spark.sql('SELECT 1 AS A, 2 AS B, 3 AS C')
dbutils.widgets.removeAll()
dbutils.widgets.multiselect('Columns', '*', choices=['*'] + df.columns)
```

Get widget value and make list.

```
widget_columns = dbutils.widgets.get('Columns')
selection = widget_columns.split(',') if widget_columns else []
print(selection)

# output ['*']
```

You can then use it in a select or elsewhere.

```
df.select(*selection).show()

+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  C|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|
+---+---+---+
```

If instead of `'*'` you want to have a list with all columns you'll need to add an extra check to do so.